# Disable some checkboxes in form

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox

I was wondering if there is an easy way of how to disable one checkbox from modifying it by user (Symfony 2.1). I was trying something like this:

```
     $builder->add('adminRoles', 'entity',  array(
            'property' => 'roleName',
            'class' => 'MyBundle:Role',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')
                    ->orderBy('r.roleName', 'ASC');
            },
            'disabled' => $this->disabledRoles,
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple'  => true
     ));
```

By $this->disabledRoles I meant an array of IDs of Role entities or entities themselves, but it seems that it just accepts boolean value which is applied for all entities (checkboxes). Thanks for your advice :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a form listener in order to customize individual elements.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

It might seem like a lot of work but it's easy enough once you work through the examples.  You will end up passing disabledRoles to the listener and then setting the disabled flag accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I still don't know how to access individual checkboxes and set them disabled. Can you provide some example code, please?